# Prove that $|A \oplus B| \geq |A-B|$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Let $A$ and $B$ be finite sets. Prove that $$|A \oplus B| \geq |A-B|.$$

I first found that \begin{align*}A \oplus B &= (A \cup B)-(A \cap B)\\&=(A \cup B) \cap (\overline{A} \cup \overline{B})\\&=((A \cup B) \cap \overline{A}) \cup ((A \cup B) \cap \overline{B})\\&=((\overline{A} \cap B) \cup \emptyset) \cup ((\overline{B} \cap A) \cup \emptyset)\\&=(\overline{A} \cap B) \cup (\overline{B} \cap A)\end{align*} and so $|A \oplus B| \geq |(A \cap \overline{B})| =|A-B|$.

Is there a simpler way of thinking about it or is this the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prove it algebraically like you did, there is (I am pretty sure) no essentially simpler way. However, it is trivial to show directly from the definitions
$$
A - B =\{a \mid a \in A \land a \notin B\} \qquad\qquad A \oplus B = \{a \mid (a \in A \land a \notin B) \lor (a \notin A \land a \in B)\}
$$
that $A - B \subseteq A \oplus B$; namely, if $a \in A - B$, then $a \in A$ and $a \notin B$, whence $a \in A \oplus B$.